# Простая математика в Python

Tags: python, математика

Я пишу консольную программу для решения математических операций и столкнулся проблемой
Постараюсь объяснить как смогу

```
def base(equation):
    ''' Функция в которую мы передаём простое математическое уравнение по типу 100-23'''
    if '%n' in str(equation):
        ''' Если в строке есть %n то пользователь просит найти процент от числа'''
        percentage_of_number = str(equation).split()
        return float(percentage_of_number[2]) / 100 * float(percentage_of_number[0])
```

И ниже проблема -> если пользователь не хочет найти процент от числа то мы выводим ему переменную
Которая как я думал должна выводится в решённом формате, но нет
при вводе уравнения по типу 100-23 не находя в нём `%n` программа выводит уравнение в первоначальном виде

```
    else:
        ''' Отдаём изначальное уравнение '''
        return equation
```

> Если нужны более подробные объяснения пишите в комментарии к вопросу

Comment: Не очень понятно что именно нужно. Если необходимо вернуть результат выражения, то можно использовать `eval(equation)` (`eval`  выполняет python код как будто его ввели в консоль). Если я ошибся в том что нужно можете, пожалуйста, привести примеры входные данные / выходные возможно это поможет понять что именно нужно.

Comment: Да именно это мне было и нужно! Благодарю за комментарий, можете продублировать его как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения результата выражения можно использовать `eval`:

```py
expression = "123 - 32"

print(eval(expression))
```

Но не забывайте что eval выполняет python код, поэтому если вы используете его для бэкенда это не безопасно.